# My wifi will not stay on anymore

Tags: wi-fi, settings

I have a Android 5.1 system a few day ago my wifi started turning it self off now it will not stay on for more than 5 minutes. I been through setting up and down I can find anything wrong accept one thing in the wifi advanced settings the web certificate section is totally empty. First advice I tried from online was infected with malware So I downloaded the the tool to check and remove. After the scan it came up clean.

Comment: If your using a Samsung device, then turn off smart network switch in WiFi settings